# How Do I Fix syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: shell

my code is

```
#!/bin/sh

clear

if [[ "$1" == "donut" ]]; then
    mkdir ~/.deb
    wget ``https://github.com/packageash/repo/blob/main/Donut.deb?raw=true ~/.deb
    dpkg --install ~/.deb/Donut.deb
    rm ~/.deb/Donut.deb
elif [[ "$1" == "nodonut" ]]; then
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/donut
else
echo "Nothing Picked To Install."
```

so how do i fix it and can i if i just try cause im trying to make a package manager in shell

Comment: The `if` has no matching `fi`.

Comment: Paste your code into [ShellCheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) fix the errors and then update your question here.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Update the question? The question is about the errors in the code. Fixing the errors in the question would invalidate the question.

Comment: @KeithThompson - precisely!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It says "Couldn't find 'fi' for this 'if'.". How are you suggesting the question should be updated? (I voted to close it.)

Comment: `" Line 14: -- SC1047 (error): Expected 'fi' matching previously mentioned 'if'. ... Fix any mentioned problems and try again."` ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238084/discussion-between-keith-thompson-and-david-c-rankin).

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are looking at only for two options and since this script is really simple, I would recommend changing the `if` to `switch case`, because the `[]`s can have different behaviors depending if you are using bash/sh/zsh. I've created a simple snippet with that.

```
#!/bin/bash
DEB_FOLDER="${HOME}/.deb"

case $1 in

  donut)
    mkdir -p ${DEB_FOLDER} #try to create folder if it doesn't exists
    wget https://cdn.glitch.me/ec7fa70f-caec-4ba9-877f-3f809b43f7ea%2FDonut.deb -O ${DEB_FOLDER}/Donut.deb #save the wget downloaded file to ~/.deb/Donut.deb
    sudo dpkg --install ${DEB_FOLDER}/Donut.deb #install the deb package"
    rm -f ${DEB_FOLDER}/Donut.deb #removes the  ~/.deb/Donut.deb file"
    ;;

  nodonut)
    sudo rm /usr/local/bin/donut
    ;;

  *)
    echo -n "Nothing Picked To Install"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks Bro But I Got One Issue Where DO I Store The Files?

Comment: I Got A Provider For Files Now But The ISsue Is Can I Use Spaces?

Comment: Hi @PokeyManatee4 I've edited the script and put some comments. The file will be saved in the directory of `$DEB_FOLDER` which will be the `home` of the user that is running the script, in my case, something like:  `/home/juan/.deb/Donut.deb`. I didn't get your second question, could you edit your first question and put some examples?

Comment: i cant fix no more because my terminal is online on codeanywhere and it was a free trial(I Wish Someone Will Pay For It:-( )

Comment: And @JuanFontes I Was Asking For A File Provider